# Using Firebase in Swift - pod install error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently writing a Swift application to use Firebase, just a course from YouTube. I have created a PodFile to try and install the Firebase libraries:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'FirestoreDemo' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FirestoreDemo

  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  pod 'Firebase/Firestore' 
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

end
```

When I remove the pod 'Firebase/Firestore' line out of the PodFile - pod install works.

When I have the line in and run pod install - it tries to install BoringSSL as a dependency. I cannot get pod install to work at all. I have tried to download BoringSSL and install manually. I have created a podspec file and tried to point Firestore to that:

pod 'Firebase/Firestore', :podspec => 'FireStore.podspec.json'

Nothing seems to work for me, have spent hours trying to get around this issue.

Everything I have read online has been to no-avail, nothing seems to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any issues with your pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'FirestoreDemo' do 
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks use_frameworks!
    # Pods for FirestoreDemo
    # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics 
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics' 
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore' 
    # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
end
```

Try `running pod repo update` to make sure you have the latest pods available and then try to run `pod install` again.

I just ran the same pod install on a brand new project and it worked without issues, but it did take a little time.  (See below dependencies that it installs and some of them take a while depending on internet speeds, etc...)
Below is the log of dependencies/pods installed from installing the 3 pods you have in your podfile:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I try and run "pod repo update".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. When I try and run "pod repo update".

$ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/********/.cocoapods/repos/master-backup fetch
  origin --progress
  error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master-backup` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose

If I run with the verbose flag, I also get the same error.

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Comment: @NOLEROBINSON Can you provide the output of the --verbose.  What version of OS and cocoapods are you on?
You can find version of cocoapods by running "pod --version" in terminal

Comment: Hi,

When I run "pod repo update --verbose" I get:

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master-backup` repo. 
If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`

Pod Version is 1.8.0
Mac Version is High Sierra (10.13.6)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure you install Cocoapod

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

#### In your Project directory

```
pod init
```

#### Podfile

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '13.0'
    
    target 'ios-core-project' do
      # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
      use_frameworks!
    
      pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
      pod 'FirebaseCore'
    
    
      # Pods for ios-core-project
    
    end
```

#### Then save Podfile and run pod install

```
pod install
```